# Can't Get Axis to Align Right on MatPlotLib 3d

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, bar-chart, axis

I'm trying to do a 3d matplot graph. I'm having trouble getting the full axis to show with nicely aligned labels. I've outlined the steps I've tried below.

1) I can set the y-axis labels using:

```
yTicks = list(range(0,90,5)
ax.set_yticks(range(len(yTicks)), True)
```

[image]

However, as you can see, the labels are very badly aligned. It also isn't matching what I've actually defined, which should have been ticks counting by 5, not 10.

2) If I try using `set_yticklabels` as well, though, the alignment fixes but it only prints part of the axis. Here is the code and image:

`ax.set_yticklabels(yTicks, verticalalignment='baseline',
                   horizontalalignment='left')`

[image]

Notice how the y-axis went from 80 to 40.

3) And if I get rid of the `True` in `set_yticks`, everything squishes together:

[image]

4) Finally, if I use both `set_yticks` and `set_yticklabels` calling `get_yticks()` in the labels function, it almost works but you can see the axis lines extend beyond the "surface" of the graph:

```
ax.set_yticks(range(len(yTicks)), True)
ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticks(), verticalalignment='baseline',
               horizontalalignment='left')
```

[image]

5) Here is a more complete version of my code for reference:

```
plt.clf()

ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

ax.bar3d(x,y,z, 
     1,1,[val*-1 if val != 0 else 0 for val in z])

xTicks = list(range(0,25,2))
yTicks = list(range(30,90,5))

ax.set_zlim(0, 1)

ax.set_xticks(range(len(xTicks)), True)
ax.set_yticks(range(len(yTicks)), True)

ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticks(), 
                verticalalignment='baseline',
                horizontalalignment='left')

ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticks(), 
                verticalalignment='baseline',
                horizontalalignment='left')

plt.savefig(file_path)
```

How can I get it to show my full axis (0-90) at intervals of 5 and have it aligned well?

6) **UPDATE**: Per the conversation below with @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, here is the issue I'm still experiencing using the following code:

```
x=[15,28,20]; y=[30,50,80]; z=[1,1,1]

plt.clf()

ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

ax.bar3d(x,y,z, 
         1,1,[val*-1 if val != 0 else 0 for val in z])

xTicks = list(range(0,25,2))
yTicks = list(range(30,90,5))
ax.set_xticks(xTicks)
ax.set_yticks(yTicks)

ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticks(), 
                verticalalignment='baseline',
                horizontalalignment='left')

ax.set_zlim(0, 1)

plt.savefig(getSaveGraphPath(save_name))
```

[image]

Comment: The second argument to `set_yticks` is a boolean, specifying whether or not the first argument are minor ticks. It does not seem to make any sense to supply a list as second argument. The real problem however cannot be solved here, because we simply don't know the actual data units of your bars. See [mcve].

Comment: You can see the actual data units of the bars in the example, but it also doesn't matter. Any values produce the same results. The issue is not the bars but the axis values and I do provide that info in my description above. You're right about `set_yticks` (different than plt.yticks()) but removing that argument produces even more terrible results. It literally stops counting the axis part way

Comment: If literally any value produces the same results, that would be the core of the problem. But I cannot reproduce this. I do not see any picture where you claim to not have used any modifications of the axis, so no, I cannot "see the actual data units of the bars in the example".

Comment: I have added my code above so you can see. You can choose any values for x, y, z as long as they fall within the label ranges I've defined.

Comment: Without actual data the only answer is the trivial fact that you can set the ticks via `ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,90,5))`.

Comment: I really don't understand what more you want, since the whole point is that it does NOT matter what the data is, the problem is the same. If you REALLY must have values, use x=[15,28,20], y=[30,50,80], z=[1,1,1]. But the point is you can use the three values I provided, 100 values, or empty data. It does not matter because I'm not talking about the bars, but the graph axis rendering itself. You should definitely be able to reproduce this. If you want specific values to try, use the three I've provided but it literally doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, you can set the ticks via `ax.set_yticks`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

x=[15,28,20]; y=[30,50,80]; z=[1,1,1]

ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

ax.bar3d(x,y,z, 
     1,1,[val*-1 if val != 0 else 0 for val in z])


yTicks = list(range(30,90,5))
ax.set_yticks(yTicks)

ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticks(), 
                verticalalignment='baseline',
                horizontalalignment='left')

ax.set_zlim(0, 1)

plt.show()
```

This will show the desired 5 unit steps on the y axis.

[image]

Comment: That is true, but the issue that prompted my original question is when done that way, the labels tend to be very badly aligned. For instance, notice how the 85 is quite a bit in front of its tick mark (this is easier to see on the very first graph image I include but can be seen on yours too). There is no way to adjust alignment using set_yticks, one has to use set_ylabels. However, that creates the aforementioned problems. I am struggling to find a permutation of instructions that both 1) sets the y-ticks and 2) sets tick label alignment without causing problems.

Comment: Mhh, I mean you can still add `ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticks(), 
                verticalalignment='baseline',
                horizontalalignment='left')` to the code in the answer if you want?!

Comment: I did, it's in the question. You can see how it makes the graph look.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about which command you report to be doing what exactly. I just updated my answer with that line and the resulting graph.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, I copy-pasted your code (just added `ax.set_xticks(xTicks)`) but it's resolving differently. For one thing, your graph ends at 16 (on the x-axis) even though the code sets the range to start at 0, while mine does go to 0. However, mine doesn't color in the full axis, only as far as there is data. Please see the update to my question for a picture of what I see.

Comment: Well, you set some ticks which are outside of the axis limits it seems.

Answer (score 0):

So after much trial-and-error, the only way I could get the graph to render axes appropriately in various limit cases is as follows. I'm not completely happy with it (notice how the last y-tick label doesn't appear) but it is the only version that has the numbers actually next to their tick marks). I had to let x and y limits be effective only if the data didn't exceed their values, whereas the z boundary is a hard limit. I don't claim to understand why these permutations are all necessary (this all is only an issue with 3D plotting), but this is the solution that works for me:

```
plt.clf()

ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

# Need to force include fake NaN data at the axis limits to make sure labels
# render correctly
#
# xLims and yLims create boundaries only if data doesn't stretch beyond them

xstart, xend = xLims
ystart, yend = yLims
x = [xstart] + x + [xend]
y = [ystart] + y + [yend]
z = [numpy.nan] + z + [numpy.nan]

# Plot graph

ax.bar3d(x,y,z,1,1,[val*-1 if val != 0 else 0 for val in z])

# Set z boundary (after graph creation)

ax.set_zbound(zBounds)

# Need to adjust labels slightly to make sure they align properly

use_x_ticks = ax.get_xticks()

### ON SOME SYSTEMS, use_x_ticks = ax.get_xticks()[1:] is needed for correct alignment ###

ax.set_xticklabels([int(x)  if x==int(x) else x for x in use_x_ticks],
                    horizontalalignment='right',
                    verticalalignment='baseline')

ax.set_yticklabels([int(y) if y==int(y) else y for y in ax.get_yticks()],
                    verticalalignment='top')

# Save graph

plt.savefig(file_save_path)
```

As you can see below, everything is nicely aligned:

[image]